# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a error when I hit my start button for my timer. I don't know why its not working. I had it working with this code before but now when I try and run it it just immediately crashes with the error.

Here is the class for my timer code:

```
package com.example.pc.mealtimers;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WegmansActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    static TextView wegmansTimerText;
    static Boolean counterIsActive = false;
    Button wegStart;
    static CountDownTimer countDownTimer;




    public static void resetTimer(){
        wegmansTimerText.setText("16:00");
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        counterIsActive = false;

    }

    public static void wegmansTimerInit() {
        if (counterIsActive == false) {
            counterIsActive = true;
            //wegButton.setText("Stop!");
            countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(960000, 1000) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    updateTimer((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                   wegmansTimerText.setText("0:00");
                }
            }.start();
        }else{
            wegmansTimerText.setText("16:00");
            resetTimer();

        }

    }

    public static void updateTimer(int secondsLeft){

        //System.out.println("TICKING");
        counterIsActive = true;
        int minutes = (int) secondsLeft / 60;
        int seconds = secondsLeft - minutes *60;
        String secondString = Integer.toString(seconds);
        if (seconds <=9){
            secondString = "0" + secondString;

        }
        wegmansTimerText.setText(Integer.toString(minutes) + ":" + secondString);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wegmans);

        wegmansTimerText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wegmansTimerText);
        wegStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    }
}
```

Here is my code for the layout in which the timer is located:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".WegmansActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back"
        android:id="@+id/backButton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="backButton" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="400°"
        android:id="@+id/degreeText"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/backButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="16:00"
        android:id="@+id/wegmansTimerText"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="60sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:onClick="wegmansTimer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My error::

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #44: Process: com.example.pc.mealtimers, PID: 2346
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.pc.mealtimers.WegmansActivity.updateTimer(WegmansActivity.java:60)
    at com.example.pc.mealtimers.WegmansActivity$1.onTick(WegmansActivity.java:33)
    at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:133)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: In which lifecyle step you call your function?

Answer (score 0):

This is just an educated guess but the NPE might occur due to the fact that you call a method on the field `wegmansTimerText` in the static method `updateTimer`.

Guess `updateTimer`through the init method gets executed before `onCreate` is called which instantiates the particular field. This way `wegmansTimerText`is null. You've got to allign the called methods for your timer correctly with the lifecycle - meaning you might need to put content of the static methods into `onCreate` or on of the following lifecycle states.

I don't have Android Studio here right now, so this isn't tested but might point you in the right direction.

Hope this helps!